# Exception thrown in very specific configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have very weird situation where I have unit test (XUnit) that try to resolve webapi controllers through Autofac ( with web api contrib).
I have a situation where If I switch my configuration in Release mode, test in x86 mode, and run my test (if debug my test then it works) it throws an exception about the fact it can't resolve the controller.
Change whatever parameters in the above configuration it then works perfectly(I am using VS2012).

I know it is very little information and can not ask for a solution, but any clue about what could have been wrong will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record , I was trying to look at the stack frame to extract the caller class of method. In release mode,  JIT may actually optimize the call stack (kind of Tail optimization) and basically remove what I expected to find (and was able to find in debug).